# Passing string variable value in Pandas dataframe

Tags: string, pandas, variables, dataframe

I have been trying to use variables for passing the string value in dataframe for various column operations, but the code is giving me wrong results. See the code below, I am using in Jupyter Notebook:

```
first_key = input("key 1: ")
second_key = input("ket 2: ")
third_key = input("ket 2: ")
```

These receive the values "Russia", "China", "Trump" for the operation in next cell as below:

```
tweets['{first_key}'] = tweets['text'].str.contains(r"^(?=.*\b{first_key}\b).*$", case=False) == True
tweets['{second_key}'] = tweets['text'].str.contains(r"^(?=.*\b'{second_key}'\b).*$", case=False) == True
tweets['{third_key}'] = tweets['text'].str.contains(r"^(?=.*\b'{third_key}'\b).*$", case=False) == True
```

But results are wrong. Any idea how to get the correct results. A small snapshot of the results is like this.

[image: Output of the code run.]

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to leverage python f-strings but forgot the "f" at the beginning.

Comment: OK, just figured out the 'f' thing it works for the column head, but how to pass the same for regex. This is needed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried cleaning up your code. You can leverage f-strings (using python-3.6+) with a tiny change to your code:

```
def contains(series, key):
    return series.str.contains(rf"^(?=.*\b{key}\b).*$", case=False)
```

If you're working with an older version of python, use `str.format`:

```
def contains(series, key):
    return series.str.contains(r"^(?=.*\b{}\b).*$".format(key), case=False)
```

Next, call this function inside a loop:

```
for key in (first_key, second_key, third_key):
    tweets[key] = contains(tweets['text'], key)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just for the sake of learning, I wanted to know how to pass the variable in the regex. thanks!

Comment: @ambrishdhaka Just like this: `tweets[key] = tweets['text'].str.contains(rf"^(?=.*\b{key}\b).*$", case=False)`

Comment: There seems to be an issue, the code `case=False` is used to make the search query case insensitive. And, the condition == is then used to check if the value is present. But, the result are all False when using `tweets[f'{first_key}'] = tweets['text'].str.contains(r"^(?=.*\b{first_key}\b).*$", case=False) == True`

Comment: @ambrishdhaka The `== True` is redundant since `contains` returns a mask anyway. Also, it should be `rf"^(?=.*\b{first_key}\b).*$"`, you're missing a leading `f`, please look at it again. Also, if the answer helps, do consider passing an upvote, thanks.

Comment: You are right. It is the same 'f' thing. Now got the correct results. And, also thanks == True is not needed. I learnt that.